# Spring Boot with Postgres application not working on Docker. Error: PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused.

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

When trying to build and run my containers using Docker 'docker-compose up' command I keep getting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I have googled for solutions and tried different things but nothing works.
My docker-compose.yaml file:

```
My docker-compose.yaml file:

version: '3.8'
services:
app:
container_name: docker-meetings
image: docker_meetings
build: ./
ports:
- "8080:8080"
expose:
- "8080"
depends_on:
- postgresqldb
postgresqldb:
image: postgres
ports:
- "5432:5432"
expose:
- "5432"
environment:
- POSTGRES_USER=postgres
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db
- POSTGRES_DB=meetingsdb
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/visma-meeting-app-withdb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/meetingsdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&stringtype=unspecified
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=db
```

Maybe anyone has run into this problem before and knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting to localhost port 5432.

If the issue persists then check if PostgreSQL is listening to TCP/IP connections.

" sudo lsof -n -u postgres |grep LISTEN "  will show the TCP/IP addresses and ports PostgreSQL is listening on.